# How to implement select all in mat-checkbox angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-material-5

Here is my html template

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <h2 class="example-h2">Select Employee</h2>    
        <section class="example-section">
            <mat-checkbox  [(ngModel)]="checked">Select All</mat-checkbox>
        </section>   
        <section class="example-section" *ngFor="let r of emp">
            <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="checked">{{r.name}}</mat-checkbox>
        </section> 
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

This is code is not working properly, if I click on select all, its selecting all the check boxes, if I select on individual check box, its also selecting
all the items.

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You should define a boolean property for emp list something like **checked** now your emp list has a property known check other than name.
2. Change ngModel for checkboxes like below

```html
<section class="example-section" *ngFor="let r of emp">
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="r.checked">{{r.name}}</mat-checkbox>  
</section>
```

3. For check all checkboxes you should add a click function to you'r Select All checkbox like below .

```html
<mat-checkbox  [(ngModel)]="checked" (click)="selectAll()">Select All</mat-checkbox>
```

And at the end add selectAll() function to you'r component i.e

```
  selectAll() {
    this.emp.forEach(element => {
      element.checked = true;
    });
  }
```

**update**

For unselect all checkboxes you can add a button like below

```html
<button (click)="unSelectAll()">UnSelect all</button>
```

and add its function in you'r ts file like below

```
  unSelectAll() {
    this.emp.forEach(element => {
      element.checked = false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, is there any way to deselect all, when unchecked the select all check box.

Comment: I will update my post , please mark the answer if it helps :)

Comment: its working almost fine, thanks again, only issue I am facing, if I click on unselect all, select all button still showing selected.

Comment: add this.checked = false; into unSelectAll() function.

Comment: Hi @Arash! I would suggest to update your function "selectAll" with the following content to make it possible to select all and deselect all on the checkbox:



    ```this.emp.forEach(element => {
      element.checked = element.checked ? false : true;
    });```

Answer (score 1):

I think @Arash suggestion is very good.

Just update his function "selectAll" to also be able to deselect as well:

```
this.emp.forEach(element => {
  element.checked = element.checked ? false : true;
});
```

Another option would be to check what value the "select all" checkbox has:

```
  public selectAll() {
    var value = this.checked ? false : true;
    this.emp.forEach(element => {
      element.checked = value;
    });
  }
```